# Is there any tooltip functionality in Graphiti?

Tags: javascript, raphael, draw2d, graphiti-js

Is there any tooltip functionality, so that on mouse over of any shape(node) it will appear showing the information for the shape.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this functionality is now available: http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/example/tooltip_diy